# Providing a report view when users enter information in SP list

Tags: reports

I am trying to create an questionnaire using a SP list, where people answer certain questions and they get aggregated to produce a summary view of what the person responded. I need for the information to be displayed right after the person submits the form, and also for the user to be able to view ONLY their responses with some additional analysis and information added by the tool. What do I need to use for this?

Comment: Which SP version are you using ? Application pages if its on server or have to dig in if you are doing completely on the client side .

Comment: Sharepoint 2013, client side.